# How to split string at word

Tags: c++

I have written an algorithm for splitting strings in C++. I just want to know how to split a string if the user wants to split words instead of characters.

My below algorithm is working properly with characters, but I am confused about how to change it to split the string if the user enters a word.

**For example, `this is the book` is splitting at `"is"` and shows the output as: `['th', 'the ', 'book']`.**

```cpp
vector<string> split(string statement, char regex = ' ') {
    statement += regex;
    string part = ""; 
    vector<string> splt;   
    for (int i = 0; i < statement.size(); i++) {
        if (statement[i] == regex) {
            splt.push_back(part); 
            part = ""; 
            continue; 
        }
        part += statement[i];
    }

    return splt; 
}
```

Above is my algorithm function.

**My main function**

```cpp
int main() {

    string line = ""; 
    cout << "Enter sentence :: ";
    getline(cin, line);


    cout << "["; 
    vector <string> _split = split(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < _split.size(); i++) {
        if (i == _split.size() - 1)
            cout << "'" << _split.at(i) << "'"; 
        else
            cout << "'" << _split.at(i) << " ', ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Please guide me on how to change this for words.

Comment: In above code line by default splits at whitespace, if you do not provide any regular expression. If you provide regular expression it will split at regular expression.

Comment: I know in above code I have used char data type but it's not applicable for string. I want to know the logic that works for strings and characters as well. It will be best if same program changed for characters and strings

Comment: string::find() can be used to find entire substrings. If you do a google, you'll find examples solving this exact problem.

Comment: regex is not a good way to handle such easy problem